# Obter max e min array

Tags: javascript

Queria obter um máximo e o mínimo de um Array. O Array vem em PHP e utilizo Json para converter para JavaScript. Utilizei função do  `Math.max.apply(null, js_array)` mas não me funciona.

```
//convert php array to javascript
var js_array = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $array_nombre).'"' ?>];
```

Comment: Coloca também o código que chega ao lado do cliente. Já depois do PHP.

Comment: O codigo que vem depois do PHP, é esse que esta na pergunta.

Comment: Os valores sao bem inserido, o que é feito é convertido o array php para a string javascript

Comment: Isso não faz sentido. O código depois do PHP já não tem PHP. Como fica esse array na página de HTML se fores ver o código fonte?

Comment: Não vejo JSON envolvido na conversão da array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, se percebi bem estás a fazer echo de uma string, dentro de `[]`. Ou seja algo como:

```
var js_array = ['0,1,2,3,4'];
```

Nesse caso tens de converter isso numa array "completa" e depois calcular o máximo e minimo.

Testa assim:

```
var js_array = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $array_nombre).'"' ?>];
js_array = js_array[0].split(',');
```

e aí já podes usar:

```js
var js_array = ['0,1,2,3,4'];
js_array = js_array[0].split(',');
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, js_array);
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, js_array);
alert('min: ' + min + ', max: ' + max);
```

Comment: No meu caso não funciona. Porque é convertido em uma string.

Comment: @akm editei a resposta...